# How to isolate $x$ from $x^y=z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

> $x^y=z$

How would I isolate $x$ from the equation above so that I get $x=...$ ?

I couldn't find anything on the internet and I have no idea how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$x^y=z$$ then $$x^{y^\frac{1}{y}} = z^\frac{1}{y}$$ and since $$x^{y^\frac{1}{y}} = x^{y \cdot \frac{1}{y}} = x^1 = x $$ we thus have $$x = z^\frac{1}{y}$$

which is also known as $$x = \sqrt[y] z$$